# adapter.notifyDataSetChange() doesnt work

Tags: android, android-adapter, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerview and it includes several rows.
each row has an imageview(heart shape) for like and dislike and what I need is changing the image of imageview each time by my click.
when I start this activity and my list sets, it works well and the image changes by clicking on imageview, but the problem is when I start another activity and get back to this activity, onclick doesn't work.
It seems my adapter doesn't notify data!
This is my code after clicking on imageview:

```
public static void afterLikeChanged(Post post) {
    if (!post.getPostIsLikedByYou()) {
        post.setPostIsLikedByYou(true);
    } else {
        post.setPostIsLikedByYou(false);
    }
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

and on the other side in adapter class:

```
boolean isliked = post.getPostIsLikedByYou();
if (!isliked) {
    holder.imglike.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_like);
} else {
    holder.imglike.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_liked);
}
```

any idea guys?!

Comment: your code seem fine, but we'd need to see more of it, can you post the complete class?

Comment: `notifyDataSetChanged()` is expensive. To notify a single item use `notifyItemChanged(int position)` And to answer your code is incomplete.

Comment: What have you done in another activity

Comment: Show us how you create and init the adapter. Is the list of objects in the adapter empty when you switch back? The use of static in your `afterLikeChanged` makes me suspisous

Comment: @twlkyao That one is a completely separate class and loads another datas.

Comment: This mean only one thing  that the `Post post` as a parameter is not the part of dataset which is bind to `Adapter`. Its a new object i think . So if this is the case you need to traverse through the list and find the  Object .

Comment: Kindly share your code

Comment: @AnesHasic no my list has not changed. just when I get back and  click on imageview I can't see any change! at the same time when I scroll the list, I see imageview has changed!(By scrolling I can see the changed, but without it, no!)

Comment: @LeviAlbuquerque my class is pretty big! would you like I send it here?

Answer (score 1):

make interface in adapter for like and dislike click event like below code ..
 Note : take boolean value for like or like and make getter setter.

```
    onItemClickListner onItemClickListner;

public interface onItemClickListner {
    void onClick(User str);//pass your object types.
}
public void setOnItemClickListner(RecyclerViewAdpater.onItemClickListner onItemClickListner) {
    this.onItemClickListner = onItemClickListner;
}
    @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ItemViewHolder holder, int position) {
    // below code handle click event on recycler view item.
    User data=userlist.get(position);
    if (!data.isliked()) {
        holder.imglike.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_like);
    } else {
        holder.imglike.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_liked);
    }
    holder.imageHeart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            onItemClickListner.onClick(data);
        }
    });
}
```

then after adapter set into recylcerview call below code..

```
   recyclerViewAdpater.setOnItemClickListner(new RecyclerViewAdpater.onItemClickListner() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(User str) {
           if (str.isLike()){
               str.setLike(false);
           }
           else{
               str.setLike(true);
           }
           recyclerViewAdpater.notifyDataSetChanged();
       }
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

**You need to update your post list before notify the adapter**

Something like this:

```
public static void afterLikeChanged(int position, Post post) {
    if (!post.getPostIsLikedByYou()) {
        post.setPostIsLikedByYou(true);
    } else {
        post.setPostIsLikedByYou(false);
    }
    // postList is a ArrayList that you passed to your adapter
    postList.set(position, post);
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not just call like that. Please try below steps:

1. Assume your current Activity is A. you will switch to activity named B
2. Using startActivityForResult(B.class, 0x0) instead of startActivity
3. Implement this in activity A:

boolean getPostIsLikedByYou = false;// This is the variable you get new value from Activity B

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // Check which request we're responding to
    if (requestCode == 0x0) {
        // Make sure the request was successful
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            getPostIsLikedByYou = data.getBoolean("getPostIsLikedByYou");      
        }
    }
}
```

4. From Activity B, do this when go back:

   Intent resultIntent = new Intent();

   resultIntent.putBoolean("getPostIsLikedByYou", "your_value_here");
   setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultIntent);

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your code is a bit seperated. Something like this will encapsulate the behaviour. All you want is to change the icon and preserve the state of the posts.

It's important to keep track of what you've saved.

Your adapter class. It's missing a lot of code but something like this.

```
List<Post> posts; // init this in constructor

public void update(List<Post> posts) {
    // do some nullchecking, maybe clone the posts. It's sent as a reference now. 
    this.posts = posts; 
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
    final Post post = posts.get(position);
    if (post != null) {
        if (post.isLiked()) {
            holder.imglike.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_liked);  
        } else {
            holder.imglike.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_like); // change name of this
        }
    }
}

public void afterLikeChanged(Post post) {
    post.setIsLiked(!post.isLiked());
    notifyDataChanged();
}

class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    // super, etc...

    // this is a lazy way to use it, not safe. 
    // You should create a listener that sends back the getAdapterPosition()
    itemView.setOnClickListener(v -> afterLikeChanged(posts.get(getAdapterPosition())));
}
```

Now make sure that you're hooking up the adapter to the recyclerview correctly. If it works the first time and not the second time, it seems like you are hooking things up in the wrong places. Use `onPause` and `onResume` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the solution!
The problem was I had this line in onResume:

```
mAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapterQuestions(this, arrayList);
```

َAfter removing this line the problem was resolved!
It seems in this section my adapter was resetting with new data, not with my previous array!
Thank you for answering me:)